# I keep getting ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: ''

Tags: python, pandas, tweepy

here is the code but every time it creates this error.
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: ''

Here is the main code. It's for posting a tweet

```
import tweepy
import pandas
import time
import creds

latest_tweeet_id =0
appkey= creds.appkey
appSecret = creds.appSecret
accessToken = creds.accessToken
acessSecret = creds.acessSecret


latest_tweeet_id =0
with open('latest.txt', 'r') as f:
    latest_tweeet_id = int(f.read())

print(latest_tweeet_id)

df = pandas.read_csv('quotes.csv', sep=';')

def tweet(msg):
    msg = msg[0:270]

    try:
        auth = tweepy.OAuth1UserHandler(creds.appkey, creds.appSecret, creds.accessToken, creds.acessSecret)

        api = tweepy.API(auth)
        try:
            api.verify_credentials()
            print("Auth Ok")
        except:
            print('Error')

        api = tweepy.API(auth, wait_on_rate_limit=True)
        api.update_status(msg)
        print(msg)


    except Exception as e:
        print(e)

for idx, rows in df.iterrows():
    if idx <= latest_tweeet_id:
        continue
    tweet(rows["QUOTE"])

    with open('latest.txt', 'w') as f:
        f.write(str(idx))
```

Here is the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):          wtflax2 (master)       
  File "app.py", line 15, in <module>       
    latest_tweeet_id = int(f.read())        
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: ''
```

The latest.txt file has only one digit, 1.

Comment: You have a stray newline in your file.

Comment: The error says that you are trying to use an empty string, which means that the file is empty.

Comment: @erip - that's `f.read()` which doesn't stop a newlines. Its empty.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that the file `latest.txt` is empty. When python reads the file, it gets the empty string, and when it tries to interpret the empty string as an integer it gives you that error.

> The latest.txt file has only one digit, 1.

The error message specifically says that the value read from `latest.txt` is the empty string, which means the file is empty. Perhaps the problem is where you are running the program from? The `latest.txt` file that Python looks for will be in the directory that you run Python from. If you have two `latest.txt` files and you are running Python from the directory that contains the empty one, that could explain what you are seeing.

Or perhaps you simply forgot to save `latest.txt` after editing it? That kind of thing has happened to me several times.

Comment: Possible that they overwrote it here: `with open('latest.txt', 'w') as f:` with nothing at some point in testing~

Comment: Thank you so much, everyone. I got the issue. I had to add a value in the latest.txt file but I had left it empty.